# Disable selection of cells in a GWT DataGrid

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I have what I hope is a simple problem with a GWT DataGrid.  I have it configured with a SingleSelectionModel and I would like all of the cells to be non-selectable.  When the user clicks on any cell in a row, I'd like the whole row to be highlighted.

What actually happens is that the text in the cell (most of my columns are TextColumns) gets selected, even though it isn't editable.

Do I have to catch browser events or is there an easier way to do this?

**Solution found**

After looking through the CellTable.css file I added "border: none !important" to the style for my cells and got the behavior I wanted.